# Class not found when calling class with Intent

Tags: android

I got the error in Intent.cs[image: error Intent]

I added android.annotation in app.gradle with.
"[image: app.gradle]

When I call class with
 Intent next = new Intent(MainMenu.this, MainActivity.class);
I got the runtime error.Error message is

```
"03-05 09:52:19.210 1339-1339/com.example.tesingphootc55 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.tesingphootc55, PID: 1339
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/example/tesingphootc55/MainActivity;
        at com.example.tesingphootc55.MainMenu$CheckSequentialClosing.onPostExecute(MainMenu.java:2125)
        at com.example.tesingphootc55.MainMenu$CheckSequentialClosing.onPostExecute(MainMenu.java:2092)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5276)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.tesingphootc55.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.tesingphootc55-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.tesingphootc55-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at com.example.tesingphootc55.MainMenu$CheckSequentialClosing.onPostExecute(MainMenu.java:2125) 
        at com.example.tesingphootc55.MainMenu$CheckSequentialClosing.onPostExecute(MainMenu.java:2092) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5276) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.tesingphootc55.MainActivity
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
                ... 14 more
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.tesingphootc55.MainActivity
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                ... 13 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class is not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: dependencies]Change dependencies as attached picture.It can solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution which I had also tried was to disable Instant run goto **File -> Settings -> Build,Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run -> Uncheck the checkbox for instant run**.

Clean you project before running it on your device.

**Edit**

Make sure to enable multidex option **if your app and the libraries it references exceed 65k methods limit**. For multidex support in gradle build add in dependencies

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

And in defaultConfig add multiDexEnabled

```
defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21 
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

For more information on multidex please visit [android developer link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)

Comment: I already close instant run and restart, clean, build. But I still got that.

Comment: And also enabled multidex ?

Comment: Can you also post the manifest.xml code to see if there is any error in package?

Comment: Yes I follow ur said,but still cant

Comment: There is a file name `AndroidManifest.xml` in your project check in that file for the line at top package="com.example.".... show me that complete line so I can check if there is problem

Comment: package="com.example.tesingphootc55"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189429/discussion-between-abid-khan-and-simto).